# ionic 2 globalization work in ios but not in android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have using ionic native globalization and ng2-translate to deal with the translation in app, below is my translation json in src/assets/i18n/en.json

```
{
  "Tab.Home": "Home",
  "Tab.Travel": "Travel",
  "Tab.Add": "Add",
  "Tab.Notice": "Notice",
  "Tab.Me": "Me"
}
```

it works in ios:
[image]

But it not works in android:
[image]

Does anyone know why this will happen or experienced before? I am beginner of ionic so Thanks a lot again~

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check the console if there are any errors on android? It looks like the json with the translations did not get loaded.

Comment: Hi Andreas, may I ask how to check the console on android? Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you run the app on your device and connect it via USB, you can use chrome (on your desktop) and navigate to `chrome://inspect`. There you should see your device/app and you can debug it just like if it was running on your desktop.

Comment: Andreas, Thanks for your tutorial, after i inspect it, it is error to load the file, please see the above picture, but do you know why /how to solve it? Thanks again~!

Comment: Is the createTranslateLoader path have problem, now is: return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');

Comment: Can you try this code? `export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}`

Comment: Hi, Andreas, still fail to load the json. I just saw the resource tree map on chrome dev tool(i.e please see above image), no assets/i18n under android_asset/www/ Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar in my new fresh ionic app run in android : GET file:///android_asset/www/assets/i18n/undefined.json net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

My problem was the access to the settings (localstorage) language that returned "undefined" language. > I have a "undefined" check.

app.component.ts

```
 initTranslate() {
// Set the default language for translation strings, and the current language.
this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');

this.settings.load().then(() => {
  this.settings.getValue('language').then(settings => {
    if ( typeof settings == 'undefined' )
      this.chooseDefaultLanguage();

    this.translate.use(settings);
  })
  .catch( result => {
    this.chooseDefaultLanguage();
  })
  .then( result => {
    this.generateMenu();
  });
});

this.translate.get(['BACK_BUTTON_TEXT']).subscribe(values => {
  this.config.set('ios', 'backButtonText', values.BACK_BUTTON_TEXT);
});
```

It may help you even it's quite a difference issue. Try to find where your app set the language and check the path.
I should probably go to the catch statment if my Promise get undefined but it's another story.